# Java Applet Class Found Locally, but Not Remotely

Tags: java, applet, server, classnotfound

I have an html file which invokes an *applet* by calling a JavaScript function from `deployJava.js`. The jar file is signed by a trusted certificate, even though that shouldn't be relevant. Whenever I run the applet on my local server, everything runs fine. But if I copy and paste the same files onto the remote server, I receive a `"Class Not Found Exception"`. How is it the the class is found when run locally, but when the same files are run remotely it's not? Is this possibly because of a setting with the remote server? Any information would help.

Comment: What is the HTML used to launch it on the server?  Do you have a link to where we can see it fail (on the server)?

Comment: The program that fails is posted here:

[Program on Server](https://edx.netl.doe.gov/eos/program2.html)

Comment: `Class Not Found Exception` Which class is identified as not being found?

Comment: The main one, TPP.class. It is inside a package titled the eosPackage.

Comment: Hmm...  (I'd already downloaded and exploded the Jar, to check that `TPP.class` was really where the HTML implied it was, and that is certainly the case..)